# How to get json like below in php api

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I have a table with 3 columns id, name, age and I have 4 records created. I am trying to create a one GET API so I can retrieve all these data and return as Array of the Object model

```
{
"status":"Success",
"data": [
         { "id":1, "name":"john", "age":34},
         { "id":2, "name":"doe", "age":32},
         { "id":3, "name":"mark", "age":24}
       ]
}
```

but when i used below code am getting null for data

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "db";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
//// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE career = 'software'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // valid email
   $Subject=mysqli_query($con,$Query);
   $i=-1;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Subject))
    {
        $i++;
    $SubjectCode[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $SubjectCode[$i]['name']=$row['name'];
    $SubjectCode[$i]['age']=$row['age'];

    }
    echo '{
    "data":'.json_encode($SubjectCode).',
    "status":"success"
}';
    //echo json_encode($response);

}else{
    $response = array("status"=>"fail", "message"=>"No software engineer available");
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Iam new to the PHP can anyone help to correct my code so i can get my desired PHP API

Comment: What is this `$Subject=mysqli_query($con,$Query);` you already did it here `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);` and you want to fetch `$result`.

Comment: should i remove that ryt?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

You define the connection as `$conn` and use it in a query `$query`, then later use use a non-existent `$con` and `$Query` in another query and use that result `$Subject` which is `false` because the query failed.  Select the columns you want in the query and use the proper variables and it is much easier:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `age` FROM `user` WHERE career = 'software'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    $response = array("data" => $row, "status" => "success");
} else {
    $response = array("status" => "fail", "message" => "No software engineer available");
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Notice you need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.

You would have seen the *Notice: Undefined variable: con* and *Notice: Undefined variable: Query* with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score -1):

The logic in the else-part looks good. But only managing once variable might be a bit smoother.

```php
<?php
// ... stuff

$output = []; // will be json_encoded at the end to a string

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE career = 'software'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // valid email
   $Subject=mysqli_query($con,$Query);

    $output['status'] = "success";
    $output['data'] = [];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Subject))
    {
        $output['data'][] = $row;
    }

}else{
    $output['status'] = "fail";
    $output['message'] = "No software engineer available";
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: its returning follwong output with empty data {"status":"success","data":[]}

Comment: Just copied most of your code, $Subject=mysqli_query($con,$Query); $Query is not defined, so I don't know if there is an error. But the database doesn't return anything. Try to change while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Subject)) to while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))